# Unable to install gatsby cli

Tags: npm, gatsby, npm-install

[image: Error]

The error that I got when tried to install gatsby cli is attached as picture . I've already installed the node in my system.

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it seems that the host that npm is trying to reach is not responding or is inaccessible. Besides of trying it again, I would suggest checking the [Gatsby on Windows documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-on-windows/).

Run:

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools --vs2015
```

Upon installing this package, it downloads and installs Visual C++ Build Tools 2015, provided free of charge by Microsoft. These tools are required to compile popular native modules. It will also install Python 2.7, configuring your machine and npm appropriately.

In addition, check that you've followed and you have installed the prerequisites to [set up your development environment](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/tutorial/part-zero/).

Comment: I have tried but still showing the same error . Even tried to install from vs package manger , But still didn't work